# How to configure Pidgin IM with sipgate SIP?

Tags: pidgin, sip

I have a sipgate SIP-account with money on it. Telephony works fine with Empathy. But how to configure Pidgin to support my SIP-account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a ticket at pidgin's BTS for implementing SIP support:
http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/9754

The free bidirectional SIP2GTalk gateway service http://gtalk2voip.com does not work with pidgin's Jingle implementation too...